# Is there any way to make this CoffeScript code simpler / smaller

Tags: coffeescript

I've just started with coffeescript,  and I saw  http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/04/20/Why-Is-Estimating-So-Hard.html  which has a little programming problem,  so I figured I'd do it in coffeescript (which seemed easy enough to do... )

anyways, I ended up with :-

```
lineEndings = ( s, len ) ->
  words = s.split ' '
  line = ''
  result = ''
  words.map ( word ) ->    
    if line.length == 0
      line = word
    else if line.length + 1 + word.length <= len    
      line = line + ' ' + word
    else     
      result = result + line + '\n'
      line = word  
  result + line

getty = "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth upon this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal"  
console.log lineEndings getty, 13
```

I'm looking for any ways I could make this simpler coffeescript.

( I just used nodejs with coffescript installed to test this )

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would write it.

```
lineEndings = (s, len) ->
  words = s.split ' '
  line = []
  result = []
  for word in words
    if line.length + 1 + word.length <= len
      line = [line..., word]
    else
      result.push line.join ' '
      line = [word]
  lastLine = line.join ' '
  result.push lastLine if lastLine
  result.join "\n"
```

There's nothing wrong with how you wrote it, though.

Answer (score 2):

1. In your case you should use `forEach` method or `for` statement instead of `map`. `map` has more specific purpose.
2. You could extract more generic method, though it's not necessary.

.

```
slice_reduce = (xs, slice_predicate, reduce_functor) ->
  reduction = nil
  slices = []
  if xs.length > 0
    for x in xs
      if slice_predicate(reduction, x)
        slices.push(reduction)
        reduction = x
      else
        reduction = reduce_functor(reduction, x)
    slices.push(reduction)
  slices         

word_wrap = (s, len) ->
  slice_reduce(s.split(/\s+/),
    ((r, w) -> r.length + 1 + w.length <= len),
    ((r, w) -> r + ' ' + w)).
    join('\n')
```